# Update access table (which are available in different backend) with values from another table using VBA

Tags: vba, database, ms-access

I need help in VBA code for access.
I have two tables of the same name and same number of fields located in two different backends. Two of the fields of the table indicates when was that particular record set has been **Created** and **Modified** (Date and Time). I need to compare all the record sets present in the Tables based on the fields **Created** and **Modified** and include the latest record set values in the current databank. If the record set has the same **Created** field values then it should check the **Modified** field values. The latest values present in the modified fields should be updated in the final table. Final table is what I am trying to reproduce. Table_1 from xxx_BE.accdb should resemble Final table after update. Table sample is shown below:

Table_1 from xxx_BE.accdb

```
Article Price   Status  Created             Modified
A       500     Bad     10.07.2019 10:30    14.02.2020 15:45
B       6000    Good    21.05.2019 15:45    
C       1500    Good    24.03.2018 08:30    25.03.2019 08:30
```

Table_1 from yyy_BE.accdb

```
Article Price   Status  Created             Modified
A       5000    Bad     10.07.2019 10:30    19.05.2020 16:45
B       6000    Good    21.01.2019 15:45    
C       9000    Bad     24.03.2018 08:30    
D       14000   Bad     30.06.2018 08:30
```

Final Table

```
Article Price   Status  Created             Modified
A       5000    Bad     10.07.2019 10:30    19.05.2020 16:45
B       6000    Good    21.01.2019 15:45    
C       1500    Good    24.03.2018 08:30    25.03.2019 08:30
D       14000   Bad     30.06.2018 08:30
```

Please note:
Table_1 is present in xxx_BE.accdb and Table_2 is present in yyy_BE.accdb. I want the final table to appear in xxx_BE.accdb.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service - please show us what code you have so far.

Comment: `DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "Microsoft Access", _
    "G:\Databank\DB_for_ppt_import_check\yyy_BE.accdb", acTable, "Table_1", "Table_1"`  When I execute this command a new table is being created, which I do not require. Also I tried using INSERT INTO Clause but did not result in the desired outcome.

Comment: This does nothing to help solve the main problem.

Comment: Yes, I know it is not solving the problem, that is the reason I would like to know which function or what is the approach I need to adopt to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have the two source tables available in the front-end, then you can create a copy of one of them in the correct back-end. You can then use some VBA to use a`UNION` query as the basis for a recordset to get a list of all of the distinct `Article`s from the two source tables. You would then loop this recordset, creating a second `UNION`-based recordset to get the corresponding data from the two tables. This latter recordset would be sorted by the two date fields. You would then write all of this data to a recordset that is based on the final table.

Something like this works on the data supplied:

```
Sub sMergeData()
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rsSteer  As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rsLookup As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rsFinal As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String
    Set db = CurrentDb
    db.Execute "DELETE * FROM tblFinal;"
    Set rsFinal = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblFinal WHERE 1=2;")
    strSQL = "SELECT Article FROM Table1 " _
        & " UNION SELECT Article FROM Table2;"
    Set rsSteer = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    If Not (rsSteer.BOF And rsSteer.EOF) Then
        Do
            strSQL = "SELECT Price, Status, Created, Modified FROM Table1 WHERE Article='" & rsSteer!Article & "' " _
                & " UNION SELECT Price, Status, Created, Modified FROM Table2 WHERE Article='" & rsSteer!Article & "' " _
                & " ORDER BY Created DESC, Modified DESC;"
            Set rsLookup = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
            With rsFinal
                .AddNew
                !Article = rsSteer!Article
                !Price = rsLookup!Price
                !Status = rsLookup!Status
                !Created = rsLookup!Created
                !Modified = rsLookup!Modified
                .Update
            End With
            rsSteer.MoveNext
        Loop Until rsSteer.EOF
    End If
sExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    rsFinal.Close
    rsSteer.Close
    rsLookup.Close
    Set rsSteer = Nothing
    Set rsLookup = Nothing
    Set rsFinal = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    Exit Sub
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "sMergeData", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume sExit
End Sub
```

Regards,

Comment: Thanks for your code. But, in my case, I have one of the source tables in the current database and the other source table is present in a different backend. (ie **Table1** is located in the current database having a backend **xxx_BE.accdb** and another table **Table1** is located in a different backend **yyy_BE.accdb**). Two tables have the same name, and the same number of fields only the record set stored varies. When I change the backend in the current database the tables in the current database needs to be updated. ie I need the final table recordset to be in the current database.

Comment: Work in the BE xxx_BE.accdb. Manually create a link to the other Table1 (Access will rename it to Table11), and create a copy of the structure of the existing Table1 to use as your final data.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a pure SQL solution with multiple steps since you can directly query other Access database tables with period qualifying references or `IN` reference. The other needed steps are required since correlated aggregates in Access have performance issues on union queries. All can be run from the database holding final table.

1. Union Query *(combine data sources)*

   ```sql
   SELECT Article, Price, Status, Created, Modified
   FROM [C:\Path\To\xxx_BE.accdb].Table_1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT Article, Price, Status, Created, Modified
   FROM [C:\Path\To\yyy_BE.accdb].Table_1
   ```

   Alternatively:

   ```sql
   SELECT Article, Price, Status, Created, Modified
   FROM Table_1 IN "C:\Path\To\xxx_BE.accdb"
   UNION ALL
   SELECT Article, Price, Status, Created, Modified
   FROM Table_1 IN "C:\Path\To\yyy_BE.accdb"
   ```
2. Make-Table Query *(create a new local table)*

   ```sql
   SELECT q.Article, q.Price, q.Status, q.Created, q.Modified
   INTO myTempTable
   FROM myUnionQuery q
   ```
3. Correlated Aggregate Subquery *(add rank by descending create/modified fields)*

   ```sql
   SELECT t.Article, t.Price, t.Status, t.Created, t.Modified,
          (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTempTable sub
           WHERE sub.Article = t.Article
             AND sub.Created >= t.Created
             AND sub.Modified >= t.Modified) AS [rank]
   FROM myTempTable t
   ```
4. Final Insert-Select Query *(filter using rank)*

   ```sql
   INSERT INTO myFinalTable (Article, Price, Status, Created, Modified)
   SELECT q.Article, q.Price, q.Status, q.Created, q.Modified
   FROM myCorrelAggQuery q
   WHERE q.[rank] = 1
   ```